# Key command to restart google app engine dev server in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm using app engine with java, developing in eclipse. Is there a way to bind restart of the server to a key? Something like ctrl+r will shut down and restart the server? Right now I terminate it manually, then need to restart it via all the context menus, it's eating a few seconds per restart,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command is selectable in Window->Preferences->General->Keys you can assign a keybinding to it.

Comment: Ah bummer don't see anything like that then.